# Hands-free mode not working on Samsung Galaxy SIII

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio, hands-free

I've activated `Hands-free mode` from the configurable set of switch-buttons
at the top of the notification panel on my Samsung Galaxy SIII, and such mode
also appears activated under `Settings -> My device -> Hands-free mode`. Such
entry reads: "Incoming calls and new notifications will be read out automatically".

However, I've tried sending myself e-mail messages and also received some WhatsApp
messages, which triggered the `Whistle` `Default notification sound` and made the
front Blue LED blink until I swiped down my notification panel. As I was saying,
however I didn't hear any voice coming from the phone reading out the notifications
aloud, so it seems like this feature is not working for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same phone running android 4.4.2. My phone does not speak email messages. It only speaks sms text, caller id info, and two other notifications. If you consult the help manual on the phone, the usage is a little clearer.

Comment: I've searched the user manual application installed on my Samsung Galaxy SIII but could not find anything on Hands-free mode. Could you please provide a more specific URL. Also, how did you manage to upgrade to 4.4 KitKat? My device upgraed automatically to Android 4.3 Jelly Bean, but later did not upgrade to any further version. Thanks.

Comment: I searched "hands free" from the help app. The result showed up under notifications. Depending on your cell carrier, you may have maxed out the software. I can't update my further.

Comment: Perhaps you have a different app then mine. I don't get any results when I search for "hands free". Do you have a URL?

Comment: I don't have a url, but,  you should be able to find the manual on the Samsung web site.

Comment: I found the PDF user manual for the Samsung Galaxy SIII [on this link](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201207/20120704064512229/i747M_UG_ENG_WEB.pdf) from [this site](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphones/SGH-I747MBABMC) but stil could not find anything on hands-free mode. Plus the model name is the GT-i9600, not sure if Samsung put a link for the wrong mobile device. Thanks.

Comment: [This link](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201302/20130228184012484/GT-I9300_UM_EU_Jellybean_Eng_Rev.1.1_130228_Screen.pdf) also has nothing on hands-free mode.

Comment: Perhaps this because the manual calls this feature "Driving mode". The manual says: "Activate Driving mode to provide audible notifications for incoming calls, messages, or event details." As you point out, the information read out in this mode is somewhat constrained. Thanks.